# App always goes back to main after enter background

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

The App has 2 viewControllers under navigationController, `UINavigationController`--(root view)-->`UIViewController`--(present modally)-->`UIViewController2`.

After entering `UIViewController2`, press home and let the App enter background, then reactive the App, it's screen goes back to `UIViewController`. This happens on real device, but not on simulator.

I had suspected that is the lack of memory, but there is few objects in `UIViewController2`. Any other reason makes the App to do so?

Update:
I found the problem when the iPhone was not connected with XCode!!!

I have just tested the App connecting with Xcode, when I press the home button to enter background, the App crashed!!! It means when I "reactive" the app, it actually restart again, and it do go to UIViewController.

I got the following errors
[image: p2]
[image: p2]

```
let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("home", withExtension: "html");
var webViewRequest:NSURLRequest!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webViewRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
    initSubviews()

}

func initSubviews() {
    let fm: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    self.mainScrollView = UIScrollView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, fm.size.width, fm.size.height))
    self.mainScrollView!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.mainScrollView!.frame.size.width * CGFloat(numPages), self.mainScrollView!.frame.size.height)
    self.mainScrollView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.mainScrollView!.pagingEnabled = true
    self.mainScrollView!.bounces = false
    self.mainScrollView!.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
    self.mainScrollView!.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(mainScrollView!.frame.size.width, 0, mainScrollView!.frame.size.width, mainScrollView!.frame.size.height), animated: false)
    self.mainScrollView!.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(mainScrollView!);

    prevWebView = runFunc.setWebView(0)
    currWebView = runFunc.setWebView(runFunc.screenWidth)
    nextWebView = runFunc.setWebView(runFunc.screenWidth*2)
    currWebView.delegate = self
    prevWebView.delegate = self
    nextWebView.delegate = self
    prevWebView.tag = 0
    currWebView.tag = 1
    nextWebView.tag = 2
    prevWebView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    currWebView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    nextWebView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    mainScrollView.addSubview(prevWebView)
    mainScrollView.addSubview(currWebView)
    mainScrollView.addSubview(nextWebView)

    currWebView.scrollView.delegate = self
    prevWebView.scrollView.delegate = self
    nextWebView.scrollView.delegate = self
    prevWebView.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal 
    currWebView.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal
    nextWebView.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal

    currWebView.loadRequest(webViewRequest);

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "loadPrevNext", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func loadPrevNext() {
    let prev = getPrev(currVolume, theChapter: currChapter)
    prevVolume = prev["volume"]!
    prevChapter = prev["chapter"]!
    prevChapterArr = runFunc.getLection(prev["volume"]!, theChapter: prev["chapter"]!)

    let next = getNext(currVolume, theChapter: currChapter)
    nextVolume = next["volume"]!
    nextChapter = next["chapter"]!
    nextChapterArr = runFunc.getLection(next["volume"]!, theChapter: next["chapter"]!)

    prevWebView.loadRequest(webViewRequest);
    nextWebView.loadRequest(webViewRequest);

}
```

Comment: do u have anything on app delegate that changes the root view controller ?

Comment: @Mr.T No. I don't set any delegate.

Comment: show your viewcontroller2 and viewcontroller view did appear and how u present view controller2.

Comment: @Mr.T there are `UIWebViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, Will these delegate cause the problem?

Comment: we can't tell u, unless u post the related code!!! Use breakpoints to see what gets hit, when enter to foreground

Comment: @Mr.T I updated the post with error screenshots.

Comment: those screenshots doesn't help much....do u have any code on view will disappear / view did disappear / or app did enter background ?

Comment: @Mr.T I did place viewWillDisappear in UIViewController, but there is not any code in it. Now, I posted the code here. Some codes were deleted for a clear look.